# Disable part of babelrc in webpack config

Tags: webpack, babeljs, webpack-4

Maybe i have the wrong approch, but i can't seem to find a solution for my problem. I want to disable babel minification, if running via webpack in development mode. My Problem the minification is defined in the .babelrc and i don't know how to modify this afterwards (in the webpack config).

Here is my babelrc (just in case)

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/typescript",
    [
      "minify",
      {
        "evaluate": true,
        "mangle": true,
        "builtIns": false
      }
    ],
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "useBuiltIns": "usage",
        "corejs": "3.0.0"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```